# Selenium in java eclipse linux

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium

I have the following error [image]

and here is my code

```
import org.openqa.*;
 import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
 import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
 public class io {

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();

}

}
```

I mention that this error appear only when a do "new ChromeDriver()" .If i let without that it don't do that and i don't know what i need to do to solve it.Please help.

EDIT: After i dowloaded the chrome driver when i execute the program it works fine but when i am debugging it suspend.Why this happens?

Comment: You have to set the System property before creating an instance of the chrome driver. Download chromedriver in your machine and add below line to your code before initializing the chromedriver. `System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","<path to chromedriver>");` .

Comment: For the above error, it appears like you have not added the `selenium-server-standalone-3.0.0-beta` to your project. You can do it by adding selenium jar to your project library. Right click on your project ->Buildpath ->Configure buildpath ->Libraries. Add your selenium-server-standalone-3.0.0-beta.jar and click on 'Apply' and then 'OK' button.

Comment: but i did that. look above at my example and you will see that this library is there in referenced libraries

Comment: i fixed it downloading chrome driver

Comment: I noticed it. Even I had similar problem once. Following the steps mentioned and restarting the Eclipse solved my issue.

Comment: Is your issue resolved after downloading and setting the system property for chromedriver?

Comment: yes but i can execute it without problem but when i debug it it send me to the debug perspective in java and i don't know why.if i debug and execute it don't work but if i only execute it works

Comment: Great! You can accept the answer in that case. Also, I would recommend opening a separate question for the issue you are facing in debug mode.

Comment: pls upvote this question so others could  respond to my second issue and maybe find this usefull

Comment: You should edit the question if you want it to be useful for others, because the error shown (`The jar file ... has no source attachment`) has nothing to do with missing Chrome at runtime... Basically you tried to open java source for a class `Preconditions` and eclipse is telling you, that it has no idea where source for this class is.

Comment: @KirilS. Yes! You are right. I missed that part in the screenshot. Thanks for correcting me anyways :)

Comment: it has. after i dowloaded that i don't have that problem anymore. i don't edit because i had that problem this guy offer me a solution and i solved that error using this file dowloaded. i can't understand why some of you downvote question even if the questions are good, it give me a solution and if you belive it or not THE SOLUTION WITH DOWLOADING WAS EXACTLY TO THIS QUESTION AND NOT OTHER QUESTION EDITED.SO I WILL NOT EDIT IT

Comment: No, the screenshot is completely unrelated to the problem you had. It's unfortunate that you keep insisting on something that makes no sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set the System property before creating an instance of the chrome driver. Download chromedriver in your machine and add below line to your code before initializing the chromedriver.

```
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","<path to chromedriver>");
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: i installed something with chrome driver but i cant find any file in the system to give the path.Look please at my last comment from the answer and respond me

Comment: Download chromedriver based on your OS. Create a drectory (say `libs`) in your project and copy the downloaded chromedriver to this folder. Then add `System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "./libs/chromedriver");`. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at my project, https://github.com/codezombies/easytest. One of the methods on my project makes chrome driver initialization happens before the tests run ( actually upon driver type selection ). With that said, i embedded the 3 types of chrome driver on different OS, and it should work as well on linux.